# Trigger.oldMap returns an Sobject there anyway to return a custom object?

Tags: apex

So i'm trying to compare the new and old trigger and synthesize what has changed.

I'm trying to access the old trigger object like so:

```
for (mycustomobj__c obj: Trigger.new) {
   mycustomobj__c oldObj = Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id);
}
```

This gives me an error:

`Illegal assignment from SObject to Trip__c`

Is there anyway for it to return a custom object and not a generic SObject?

Comment: The collections in triggers are typed so `mycustomobj__c old = Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id);` will compile and work.

Comment: Did you forget the = sign and the property name?

Comment: @KeithC This is a legit question. Haven't you ever tried to use Trigger context variables in a class?

Comment: @chrisjlee You probably mis-copied what you meant to say, but I think I know what you meant. Take a peek at my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox The question makes no mention of a separate class but I think you are right to work out that that is the cause here. Parameter passing via the trigger context statics is not IMHO a pattern to be encouraged though.

Comment: @KeithC Definitely bad practice, I agree.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sorry, I don't know any better. What is the appropriate "better" way of doing things. I'm open to any feedback. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trigger.new, Trigger.old, Trigger.newMap, and Trigger.oldMap static variables only have a specific SObject when used in the body of a trigger. When used in a *class*, they are always the SObject versions (`SObject[]` for the two lists, and `Map<Id, SObject>` for the two maps).

There are several ways to approach this. You can either cast a single element to the correct type, cast the entire collection to the correct type, or simply use generic [SObject methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm), such as get, put, getSObjects, putSObject, and getSObject. You'll want to read the manual for an exhaustive list of what you can do with the generic SObject type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see assignemnt in your code...I belive, you are trying to do below.. I have tried this in my org and faced no issue related to typeCasting.. Can you paste your code to understand this better.

```
trigger TestTrigger on batch__c (before update) {
batch__c a ;
for (batch__c obj: Trigger.new) {
    a = Trigger.oldMap.get(obj.id);
}
   system.debug('aaaa'  + a );
}
```